# Pig: Force one mapper per input file

Tags: apache-pig, input-split

Follow up to [Pig: Force UDF to occur in Reducer or set number of mappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735696/pig-force-udf-to-occur-in-reducer-or-set-number-of-mappers) . I have a UDF that's running as a map step in my pig workflow. It takes a list of X files, 1 per each reducer that saved it from a prior step. I want there to be X mappers (1 per input file) to run this UDF because it's very time consuming so Pig isn't running it as parallel as I want. Based on [Hadoop streaming: single file or multi file per map. Don't Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027594/hadoop-streaming-single-file-or-multi-file-per-map-dont-split) I figured the solution was to prevent splitting so I made a pig Load Func like.

```
public class ForceMapperPerInputFile extends PigStorage {
    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() {
        return new MapperPerFileInputFormat();
    }
}
class MapperPerFileInputFormat extends PigTextInputFormat {
    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(JobContext context, Path file) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

When I used this it has the exact opposite effect of what I wanted, the number of mapper tasks decreased by nearly half.

How can I actually force exactly one mapper per input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET pig.noSplitCombination true;`

(or `-Dpig.noSplitCombination=true` as one of the command-line options when running the script)

Comment: Apparently my input files were sufficiently skewed that this made things worse, but thanks this did force one mapper per input file.

Comment: Doesn't this result in one mapper per block though? For files larger than the block size, you'd still get more than 1 mapper right? How would I go about this if my files are for instance 5GB and I want to force them into one mapper? And I don't want to set the maxCombinedSplitSize to an arbitrary number...